# why df.col.rename('sth', inplace=True) doesn't work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that it's not a serious problem and there are some other ways to solve it, but I tried to rename a column using '`rename`' and it works but not 'inplace'. Although I set `inplace=True`.

`df.col.rename('new col', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website has some good examples: 
https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-dataframe-rename/

```
df_org.rename(columns={'A': 'a'}, inplace=True)
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Yeah, It worked. I was making a mistake by calling 'rename' on a column instead of the df.

Comment: Cool! stay safe!